# Should the projection morphisms of products in category theory be epic?

Tags: category-theory

I recently try to take a look at category theory, and reached a point where products are defined: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_(category_theory)

It basically says that for the product of object $A$ and $B$, there exists morphisms $\pi_1: A \times B \to A$ and $\pi_2: A \times B \to B$ such that any object with 2 morphisms that can be composed with a unique right factor and $\pi_1, \pi_2$, respectively.

However, the definition baffles me because it failed to mention that $\pi_1, \pi_2$ are epimorphisms. Shouldn't they be, since according to my intuition, there should be an element in $A \times B$ of each combination of elements in $A$ and $B$? Or otherwise the epimorphisms are automatically implied but I failed to see?

Answer (score 3):

Objects aren't sets so there is no meaning in talking about the "elements" of $A\times B$. That said, we can use the tools of internal languages to write expressions that look like normal set-theoretic, element-wise reasoning, but stand for categorical expressions. This is an approach that can simplify things greatly, but it's probably worth spending some time getting used to using the usual categorical language directly first, and it definitely isn't the case that set-theoretic reasoning can be used willy-nilly.

As Max points out, $A\times 0 \cong 0$ in many categories, e.g. $\mathbf{Set}$. That makes even the first projection, $\pi_1 : A\times 0 \to A$, factor through the $0$ map. In the context of $\mathbf{Set}$, $f \circ \pi_1 = g \circ \pi_1$ simply becomes a vacuous condition and so $\pi_1$ being an epimorphism would imply that $f = g$ for all $f, g : A \to B$ which is obviously not true.

Comment: great, so it's implied, thx. yeah it takes a while to switch to thinking in terms of morphisms. will try my best to get used to it.

Comment: There is no $\langle id, id \rangle $ though

Comment: It seems for such an argument to work, one needs at least one map $A\to B$ and one map $B\to A$. Without the assumption that such maps exist, it isn't true. For instance, pick $A$ any set and $B=\emptyset$ in $Set$

Comment: @Max Point, I wasn't thinking.

Comment: yeah right. according to the definition, product of morphisms should be indicated by the pair of morphisms from other object, and $<id, id>$ means $id : A_1 \times A_2 \to A_1$ while $A_1 \times A_2 = A_1$, which can't be.

Comment: I don't know what a nice necessary and sufficient conditiok would be though. The existence of said mappings is clearly sufficient (and it's objectwise, i.e. one mapping gives one epimorphism) but not necessary (it's easy to find examples)

Comment: so actually $\pi_i$ aren't necessary to be epimorphism then? and specifically they don't even have to be in the category $\mathbf{Set}$?

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr Correct. I probably shouldn't answer questions after being awake for more than 24 hours. In particular, $A\times\emptyset = \emptyset$ and the empty function is not a surjection onto anything but the empty set.

Comment: @DerekElkins would that be the case then if we drop the possibility of initial objects? it looks to me it fails just because of the possible existence of initial objects.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr For $\mathbf{Set}$, $\pi_i : A_1\times A_2\to A_i$ will be surjective whenever both $A_i$ are non-empty. So removing the empty set from $\mathbf{Set}$ would mean all projections in the the resulting category would be epimorphisms.

Comment: But to be clear, in an arbitrary category this has no reason to hold at all. For instance, in the opposite of commutative rings, products are tensor products.